# Redirect 301 function doesn`t work from a link with multiple variables to a link with no variables

Tags: .htaccess, apache2

currently I am testing a `.htaccess` redirect from a development domain to the live domain.

The problem is that the link from the development domain is something like this:

```
/foo/bar?page=1&sortBy=name&sortOrder=asc
```

and the live domain is something like this

```
http://www.livedomain.com/foo-bar.aspx
```

I tried different versions and I can`t manage to make them work, for example:

All with `RewriteEngine On`

1. With or without `/$` on the end of the `RewriteRule` *pattern*:

   ```
   Redirect 301 /foo/bar?page=(.)&sortBy=(.*)&sortOrder=(.*)/$  http://livedomain.com/foo-bar.aspx
   ```
2. Again, with or without `/$` on the end of the `RewriteRule` *pattern*:

   ```
   Redirect 301 /foo/bar?page=([0-9]+)&sortBy=([a-zA-Z]+)&sortOrder=([a-zA-Z]+)/$ http://livedomain.com/foo-bar.aspx
   ```
3. And...

   ```
   RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^page=([^&]+)&sortBy=([^&]+)&sortOrders=([^&]+)$
   RewriteRule /foo/bar?page=%1&sortBy=%2&sortOrder=%3 http://www.livedomain.com/foo-bar.aspx/?  [QSA]
   ```

They don`t work, any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Your rewrite rule is not correct. You only use the query string to match and backreferences would go in the substitution string not the pattern.

Give this rule a try.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^page=(.+)&sortBy=(.+)&sortOrders=(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^foo/bar$ http://www.livedomain.com/foo-bar.aspx/?  [R=301,L]
```

Comment: `sorry , but no` that tells me nothing. What doesn't work? And have you cleared your cache. If you are using that exact query string, the rule should work as I've tested it. You need to provide more details and the outcome you expect

Comment: Do you have rewrite or .htaccess enabled? if you put garbage text at the top of your .htaccess and try to load the page do you get an error?

Comment: yes , it`s a laravel project and i need it to redirect me to the public folder and if i put garbage text it gives me internal server error 500

Comment: which htaccess are you putting it in. The dev or live?

Comment: dev , and i am accessing the dev page | from dev to live

Comment: Are you putting these rules above your Larvel rules?

Comment: i tried top and bottom , tried most of these tricks  when i copied your code

Comment: So it just loads the page and not redirects? as that correct?

Comment: This is good and working redirect rule. @SheFu: Make sure this rule is in site root .htaccess as very first rule.